# I am 182 cm tall. Is a road bike with a frame height 54cm good for me?

Tags: road-bike, frames, bike-fit

I have an option to buy a road bike that has the height of the frame 54 cm : https://www.willhaben.at/iad/kaufen-und-verkaufen/sport-sportgeraete/top-rennrad-ktm-strada-nur-9-3-kg-alles-shimano-ultegra-132209154/ . I am 182 cm tall. When I went to a shop and asked the "expert" about the bike, he suggested me to buy the bike with a frame of 56 cm.

Is there a big difference between the two sizes? Should I buy the bike, or it doesn't fit to my height?

Comment: Measure your inseam and use one of the many sizing charts / calculators on the Internet.

Comment: You need to try it and see how it works, but I'm going to guess it's probably not going to be a good fit. For what its worth, I'm 180 cm and my preferred road frames tend to mostly be 58's. It depends on arm, torso and leg lengths and personal preference.

Comment: I'm 182cm and all the bikes I own are 56, except for one cyclocross bike which is 54. But then my older 1990 steel bike has a much longer top tube than my more modern 2012 bike. In your place I'd go for a 56cm. This said a magazine claimed that Peter Sagan rides a bike that is actually smaller than his fitting size because the frame is lighter and stiffer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am 175cm tall. I rode a road bike recently with a 56cm frame. I it had been any bigger I wouldn't have been able to ride it safely. 54 or 52cm would have been a better fit.

I suspect that a 54cm frame would be a bit small for you, but not painfully so. Get a 56 if you can.

Answer (score 1):

I am 183 cm tall and ride size 55. I have relatively short legs, so I had a custom frame with longer than usual top tube made. For a person with more usual proportions a normal 56 would probably be fine. As already said, it depends on the exact dimensions and angles of that particular model.